# How libGdx pass int number to texture?

Tags: java, int, libgdx, textures

Well, into my actor class
I am drawing actor as image

```
        caja = new Texture("minerjpg/box.jpg");
        miCaja =new TextureRegion(caja,Constants.size,Constants.size);
       public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) 
       {
          int x=Constants.startX+Constants.size*matPosX;
           int y=Constants.startY+Constants.size*matPosY;
          batch.draw(miCaja, x, y);
       }
```

So if I need change actors image i am just changing caja img.
But if i need white a number as a actor
What should i use??
How can i pass int to Texture or texture region??

```
    public boolean Intento(){
        setDisarmed(true);
        if(isBomb()){
            dispose();
            caja = new Texture("minerjpg/bomb.jpg");
            miCaja =new TextureRegion(caja,Constants.size,Constants.size);
            return false;
        }else{
            dispose();
            int aux=logicaJuego.recorrer(matPosX, matPosY);
            System.out.println(aux);

              //here should be pass from int to texture -_-
              //I have read a lot of manual, but noone explained it
            caja = new Texture(imageNumero);
            miCaja =new TextureRegion(caja,Constants.size,Constants.size);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. There's no Texture constructor that takes an int. If you have multiple Textures that you want to choose from, create an array of Textures and call `miCaja.setTexture(texturesArray[imageNumero]);`. You might have to also call `miCaja.setRegion(0,0,1,1);` depending on how you are using your TextureRegion.

Comment: By the way, if this method is called often, you should not be creating new Texture objects, because it will make the game stutter. Load all of your textures for the scene in the `create()` method. And never have an object call `dispose()` on itself--this will be a big source of unwanted crashes. Only an owner of an object should call dispose on it.

Comment: Well, I just want to, change the image that have this actor, and change it for some number, with out take change position or other caracteristics of actor.

Comment: So i shouldnt create texture away of create metod??
dispose is internal metod, for destroy images on graphic card.

Comment: No, because then you are loading the texture over and over for no reason. It will cause stuttering in your game. Also, you should be using a TextureAtlas to avoid having many draw calls. A TextureAtlas stores many TextureRegions on a single Texture so all your sprites can be drawn in one draw call. Every draw call takes up a lot of CPU time so you need to minimize them.

Comment: You should read this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#textureatlas

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is bad practice to store all your textures as separate files. You should read up on using a TextureAtlas here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#textureatlas

Second, you should not be loading textures and disposing them over and over. That will make your game stutter and be unplayable.

In your Game subclass or Screen subclass `create` method, you should load your images from a TextureAtlas. Then you can store all your TextureRegions in an array, so you can load them by integer like you want to do. A TextureAtlas has only one Texture that must be disposed in the `dispose` method. You should not manually call `dispose`. The owner of the Game or Screen subclass will call it.

Then pass your array of TextureRegions into the constructor of your Actor subclass, and you actor can use whichever TextureRegion it needs to at any time without causing any loading to occur.